# *apply com funções de três argumentos no R

Tags: r, funções, apply

Eu criei uma função de três argumentos e quero aplicá-la a uma matrix 200 X 3 onde em cada linha estão os três argumentos que preciso usar na função. Como resultado eu obteria um vetor de tamanho 200. Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 4):

Se você possui uma lista, e quer chamar uma função usando os elementos dessa lista como parâmetros, você pode usar `do.call`:

```
minhafuncao <- function(a, b, c) {
    return(a * b + c)
}

minhafuncao(1, 2 3)
do.call("minhafuncao", list(1, 2, 3))
```

Para converter um array em uma lista, pode-se usar `lapply` com a função identidade:

```
x <- array(1:3, dim=c(3,1))

do.call("minhafuncao", lapply(x, identity))
```

Juntando isso, pode-se chegar ao que está procurando:

```
x <- array(1:15, dim=c(5,3))

apply(x, 1, function(arr) do.call("minhafuncao", lapply(arr, identity)))
```

Explicando: o `apply` aplica a função a cada linha do array, que por sua vez é um array `3x1`; converto esse array `arr` numa lista, e uso essa lista como argumentos para `minhafuncao`.

[Exemplo no ideone.](http://ideone.com/CSZZ5v) Nota: sou iniciante em R, não sei se essa é a melhor maneira, mas pelo menos funciona como o esperado.

Comment: Muito obrigada, apesar de ser mais complicado funciona. Foi uma grande ajuda.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode fazer diretamente com o apply, separando os três argumentos da linha como os parâmetros.

```
Resultado <- apply(matrix, 1, function(linha) suafuncao(linha[1],linha[2],linha[3]))
```

Neste caso você esta usando o primeiro elemento da linha como o primeiro argumento da função, o segundo elemento da linha como segundo argumento, e o terceiro elemento da linha como terceiro argumento.

Comment: Muito Obrigada! Era exatamente isso

Comment: Por nada @user11849! Se você acha que a resposta atendeu à sua necessidade, você pode aceitá-la! Abraços